# Xen DomU (Guest) OS on different hard disk to Dom0?

Tags: linux, xen, hypervisor

I have followed the guide provided on the [Ubuntu Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen) for Xen and I have successfully installed eight guest OS's on a different machine.

In the guide, I use the command: `sudo lvcreate -L 4G -n ubuntu /dev/<VG>` to create my guest OS disks, where  is the Volume Group.

However, on this machine I have used all space on one disk for the installation of the OS, and have three other disks available which I would like to use to install guest OS disks.

```
PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree 
/dev/sda5  poweredge lvm2 a-   232.59g 44.00m
```

Is it possible to run a guest OS on a different disk? If so, what is the command?

Comment: Add the new disks to your volume group?

Comment: How can I add the disks to a volume group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is relatively trivial to resolve. If you've got many disks, you'll need to first prepare the disks (format to correct filesystem type) and then use vgcreate command to make the volume group. You'll then have each disks PV and VG listed respectively so you can specify which VG you use to create your LV.